# Why is the 'print' option missing when right-clicking a PDF?

Tags: windows-10, pdf, context-menu

For some reason, the "print" option no longer appears when right clicking a PDF file on my Windows 10 desktop. Because of this, I'm forced to open and print PDFs individually rather than being able to select and print up to 15 at a time.

Strangely, this issue only applies to PDFs, as the print option ***is*** available when right-clicking photos, Word documents, and .txt files.

**How can I fix the print option not appearing when right-clicking a PDF file?**

[image: Missing print option for PDF]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to [Arc on the Windows 10 Forums](https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/53661-right-click-command-menu-missing-print-option-pdfs.html#post708347) for finding the solution!

> **The right click print option will be available after installing a [PDF
>   application] with print capability.** Install Adobe Reader DC or Nitro
>   PDF Reader. Associate the PDF with it. Select multiple PDF files in a
>   folder. Right click on the selection.

Context menu with Adobe Reader DC as default PDF reader (***print available***):

[image: Adobe Acrobat Reader PDF context menu]

Context menu with Microsoft Edge as default PDF reader (***no print option***):

[image: Microsoft Edge PDF context menu]

Answer (score 1):

This bug also appears on Windows 7 and I found a workaround:

1. Select ALL (ctrl-A if only pdfs in the folder) of the pdf files in the folder you want to print.
2. UNselect ONE file (any one, doesn't matter)
3. Right click one of the selected files (Print option appears! Print them now.)
4. Unselect the files which are printing and right click 'print' the file you left out before.

It's helpful but not necessary to have 'checkboxes next to selections' (or however it is worded) active in folder options

Comment: It works for me on Win10. I am still curious why it works and what is the root cause...

Answer (score 0):

We were struggling with this issue due to the fact that our organization uses a program that makes calls to the same print function that exists in the context menu (an unfortunate design choice but one we have no control over). Many users log in to the same computers and Windows 10 defaults to using Edge. Setting Acrobat Reader as default PDF reader is ideal, and we have done that using the DISM method of setting the default program. However, even that causes a prompt for users that says "How do you want to open this file?" To avoid unnecessary helpdesk calls, I was able to find where to add the print option to the context menu when Edge is the default PDF reader:

This is specific to a Windows 10 computer that has Adobe Acrobat Reader installed. The exported registry key looks like this:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AppXd4nrz8ff68srnhf9t5a8sbjyar1cr723\Shell\print\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Adobe\\Acrobat Reader DC\\Reader\\AcroRd32.exe\" /p /h \"%1\""
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the first post, you will need to set the .pdf default application viewer.
Type 'Choose default applications by file type' into search.   Scroll down to .pdf type and select the appropriate default app.